# How do I make HUnit print linebreaks in assertion failures?

Tags: haskell, hunit

Some of my HUnit tests compare fairly large structures with `assertEqual`. It's hard to spot errors in these since HUnit prints the strings on one line. What I'd like to do is use `Text.Groom` to pretty print these structures, but if I pass a string to `assertEqual` the line breaks are displayed as `\n` so it makes the output even harder to read.

How do I make HUnit, `assertEqual` in particular, print the groomed strings with linebreaks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assertEqual` is just a call to `assertBool` with the equality comparison as the `Bool` and the shown version of your data structures as the `String`. So write yourself a function that calls `assertBool` with a different error string and you're done.

Comment: Actually it had a call to `assertfailure` and not `assertBool`, but exactly what I was looking for nonetheless, thanks!